# How to I add a single object into an array

Tags: java, arrays, object

For my project I need to add a Creature into an array of creatures thats created in a room

```
public class Room 
{
    String name;
    String description;
    String state;

    Creature [] creatures = new Creature[10];

    public Room(String roomName)
    {
      name = roomName;

    } 

    public String toString()
    {
       String retValue = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < creatures.length; i++) {
           retValue = retValue + creatures[i].toString();
       }
       return retValue;
    }

    public void addCreature(String creatureName)
    {    

        for (int i = 0; i < creatures.length; i++)
        {
         if(creatures[i] == null)
         {     
          creatures[i] = new Creature(creatureName);
         } 
        }

    }
}
```

when I do this, it overwrites the entire array, what can I do to add a single creature to the array?

Comment: Do you mean to append to an existing array?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, right now the array is empty, so when I call this function in man, it will add a new creature into the array of creatures in the object

Answer (score 3):

Use `break` statement.

```
if(creatures[i] == null)
{
    creatures[i] = new Creature(creatureName);
    break;
}
```

Comment: @K091916 Edit you question to show the code that you are trying and the stacktrace that you have.

Comment: I have no idea what your stacktrace is showing but based upon your above code, the `toString` should also check make sure that the `creatures[i]` is not null.

Comment: when I use the original code, for my output I get 10 of the same creature. What I'm trying to do for example is to be able to add 5 creatures, and not overwrite the entire array

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have only a fixed size. When you write `new Creatures[10]`, it means that your creatures array has at maximum 10 elements inside of it.

You can add items in two different ways:

1. You can copy the array and make it bigger, and then add the item
2. You can use `ArrayList`, which is a class which automatically does #1 for you

I would recommend ArrayList:

**ArrayList**:

```
List<Creature> creatures = new ArrayList<>();

public void addCreature(String creatureName) {
    creatures.add(new Creature(creatureName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you miss one condition in if clause. I guess it should be

```
if(current == null || current.getCreatureName() == null) {

   creatures[i] = new Creature(creatureName);
}
```